# using React.Children.toArray for arrays and in console still asking for key prop

Tags: reactjs, next.js

In Next.js MUI Project I am using React.Children.toArray(array.map(...)) code to resolve the unique key error in the console. But It's showing the error again and again.
I've looked for solution online but can't find any suitable solution here is my code,

```
return (
    <Section
      title={GalleryConfigData.title && GalleryConfigData.title}
      subTitle={GalleryConfigData.description && GalleryConfigData.description}
    >
      {Array.isArray(GalleryConfigData.galleries) &&
        GalleryConfigData.galleries &&
        GalleryConfigData.galleries.length > 0 && (
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            {React.Children.toArray(
              GalleryConfigData.galleries.map((Gallery) => (
                <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={3}>
                  <Paper variant="translucent">
                    <Card sx={optionStyles}>
                      {Gallery.image && (
                        <CardMedia
                          component="img"
                          alt={Gallery.title}
                          // height={Gallery.height ? Gallery.height : 420}
                          image={Gallery.image}
                          sx={{
                            border: "none",
                            width: "100%",
                            aspectRatio: "1/1",
                          }}
                        />
                      )}
                      {(Gallery.title || Gallery.description) && (
                        <CardContent sx={{ p: 0.5 }}>
                          {Gallery.title && (
                            <Typography
                              gutterBottom
                              variant="h3"
                              component="h3"
                              color="primary.main"
                            >
                              {Gallery.title}
                            </Typography>
                          )}
                          {Gallery.description && (
                            <Typography variant="body1" color="primary.light">
                              {Gallery.description}
                            </Typography>
                          )}
                        </CardContent>
                      )}
                      {Gallery.buttons.length !== 0 && (
                        <CardActions
                          sx={{
                            mt: "auto",
                            pb: 2,
                            px: 0.5,
                            justifyContent: { xs: "center", md: "flex-start" },
                            justifySelf: "flex-end",
                          }}
                        >
                          {React.Children.toArray(
                            Gallery.buttons.map((button) => (
                              <Button
                                component="a"
                                href={button.url && button.url}
                                sx={{
                                  px: 0,
                                }}
                                aria-label={`${button.text} about ${Gallery.title}`}
                                // size="small"
                              >
                                {button.text && (
                                  <>
                                    {button.text} <KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
                                  </>
                                )}
                              </Button>
                            ))
                          )}
                        </CardActions>
                      )}
                    </Card>
                  </Paper>
                </Grid>
              ))
            )}
          </Grid>
        )}
    </Section>
  );
```

and the error is [image: error image]

my dependency versions are leatest.

I was trying to resolve the unique key problem using `React.Children.toArray(array.map(...))` but getting the unique key error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the prop `key` with a unique key to your nearest element of `map` instead of using `React.Children.toArray`. In your code, it should be `Grid` and `Button`.

*Note that I've also added `index` param to `map` to make unique keys.*

```
return (
  <Section
    title={GalleryConfigData.title && GalleryConfigData.title}
    subTitle={GalleryConfigData.description && GalleryConfigData.description}
  >
    {Array.isArray(GalleryConfigData.galleries) &&
      GalleryConfigData.galleries &&
      GalleryConfigData.galleries.length > 0 && (
        <Grid container spacing={2}>
          {GalleryConfigData.galleries.map((Gallery, index) => (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={3} key={Gallery.image + index}>
              <Paper variant="translucent">
                <Card sx={optionStyles}>
                  {Gallery.image && (
                    <CardMedia
                      component="img"
                      alt={Gallery.title}
                      // height={Gallery.height ? Gallery.height : 420}
                      image={Gallery.image}
                      sx={{
                        border: "none",
                        width: "100%",
                        aspectRatio: "1/1",
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                  {(Gallery.title || Gallery.description) && (
                    <CardContent sx={{ p: 0.5 }}>
                      {Gallery.title && (
                        <Typography
                          gutterBottom
                          variant="h3"
                          component="h3"
                          color="primary.main"
                        >
                          {Gallery.title}
                        </Typography>
                      )}
                      {Gallery.description && (
                        <Typography variant="body1" color="primary.light">
                          {Gallery.description}
                        </Typography>
                      )}
                    </CardContent>
                  )}
                  {Gallery.buttons.length !== 0 && (
                    <CardActions
                      sx={{
                        mt: "auto",
                        pb: 2,
                        px: 0.5,
                        justifyContent: { xs: "center", md: "flex-start" },
                        justifySelf: "flex-end",
                      }}
                    >
                      {Gallery.buttons.map((button, index) => (
                        <Button
                          key={button.text + index}
                          component="a"
                          href={button.url && button.url}
                          sx={{
                            px: 0,
                          }}
                          aria-label={`${button.text} about ${Gallery.title}`}
                          // size="small"
                        >
                          {button.text && (
                            <>
                              {button.text} <KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
                            </>
                          )}
                        </Button>
                      ))}
                    </CardActions>
                  )}
                </Card>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          ))}
        </Grid>
      )}
  </Section>
);
```

Comment: tried that as well doesn't work. also tried using the .random() method still doesn't work.

Comment: Could you copy your error message to your answer instead of the screenshot? It's so small, and I cannot see what's going on with your error, @AkhlakHossainJim

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you are not giving each block inside the map function a prop named "key", so the following should work

```
return (
<Section
  title={GalleryConfigData.title && GalleryConfigData.title}
  subTitle={GalleryConfigData.description && GalleryConfigData.description}
>
  {Array.isArray(GalleryConfigData.galleries) &&
    GalleryConfigData.galleries &&
    GalleryConfigData.galleries.length > 0 && (
      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        {React.Children.toArray(
          GalleryConfigData.galleries.map((Gallery, index) => (
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={3} key={index} >
              <Paper variant="translucent">
                <Card sx={optionStyles}>
                  {Gallery.image && (
                    <CardMedia
                      component="img"
                      alt={Gallery.title}
                      // height={Gallery.height ? Gallery.height : 420}
                      image={Gallery.image}
                      sx={{
                        border: "none",
                        width: "100%",
                        aspectRatio: "1/1",
                      }}
                    />
                  )}
                  {(Gallery.title || Gallery.description) && (
                    <CardContent sx={{ p: 0.5 }}>
                      {Gallery.title && (
                        <Typography
                          gutterBottom
                          variant="h3"
                          component="h3"
                          color="primary.main"
                        >
                          {Gallery.title}
                        </Typography>
                      )}
                      {Gallery.description && (
                        <Typography variant="body1" color="primary.light">
                          {Gallery.description}
                        </Typography>
                      )}
                    </CardContent>
                  )}
                  {Gallery.buttons.length !== 0 && (
                    <CardActions
                      sx={{
                        mt: "auto",
                        pb: 2,
                        px: 0.5,
                        justifyContent: { xs: "center", md: "flex-start" },
                        justifySelf: "flex-end",
                      }}
                    >
                      {React.Children.toArray(
                        Gallery.buttons.map((button, btnIndex) => (
                          <Button key={btnIndex}
                            component="a"
                            href={button.url && button.url}
                            sx={{
                              px: 0,
                            }}
                            aria-label={`${button.text} about ${Gallery.title}`}
                            // size="small"
                          >
                            {button.text && (
                              <>
                                {button.text} <KeyboardArrowRightIcon />
                              </>
                            )}
                          </Button>
                        ))
                      )}
                    </CardActions>
                  )}
                </Card>
              </Paper>
            </Grid>
          ))
        )}
      </Grid>
    )}
</Section>
```

);

Comment: tried that as well doesn't work. also tried using the .random() method still doesn't work.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the number which we are using as a key prop so using the random function won't help as long as you are not using the prop at the correct place. 

I would suggest you to try encapsulating all the code inside the map function block in a `<div key={index}>` and keep the rest of code as it was previously.

Comment: I did not working